# Vocal-Melodies& VocalLines

Tags: theory, voice

What is a vocal melody or a vocal line? Are they the same. Is it the melodies of the lyrics you're singing without the words? Please explain

Comment: Is the vocal melody based off the lyrics? Let say I'm an artist and I hear an instrumental, and start writing lyrics to that instrumental, would that be the vocal line of the song? Basically is the vocal line the melodic structure that the lyrics create?

Answer (score 2):

A 'vocalist' is a singer.  The 'vocal line' or 'vocal melody' is the tune he sings.  If an instrument 'doubles the vocal line' it plays the same notes that are being sung.

Comment: So the vocal melody is essentially based off the lyrics? Let say I'm an artist and I hear an instrumental, and start writing lyrics to that instrumental, would that be the vocal line of the song? Basically is the vocal line the melodic structure that the lyrics create?

Comment: Lyrics are words.  Tunes are tunes.  When you do both at once it can be called a 'vocal line'.  Or I suppose just humming a tune without words would still be a 'vocal line'.  Or when  Whitney Houston makes an absolute meal of one syllable - 'I will always love y...o...u.....'  it's still a vocal line, though the lyrics don't have much to do with it!

Don't over-think this.  The 'vocal line' is the notes a vocalist sings.  It might be copied or repeated  by other instruments, but it starts off as what she sings.

Answer (score 0):

The vocal line is specifically referring to the form of the melody, does it go up and down like a pyramid, do you have waves or do you have something resembling runs?

A vocal melody is a melody specifically written for singers, it operates mostly like any good melody written for any instrument but for a few caveats.

These melodies jump a lot less and when they jump they don't jump anything more than a fourth (Octave excluded). You also would not have arpeggiated chords in a vocal melody.

Comment: I've heard vocal line used to describe different things.  Is it common in the study of music theory to use the term "vocal line" to describe the visual graphical representation of the melody sung by the vocalist?  Would it be the same as  "melody line" or would a graphical representation of the vocal line be separate from a graphical representation of the melody line?  I am sure a graphical representation of the melody could be useful in analyzing a musical composition or song but I was not aware that "vocal line" was a standardized term for such a representation.